# Is there a PHP equvalent to Python's Counter object?

Tags: php, counter

In Python, there exists a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class that allows me to do this:

```
counter = Counter()
counter[2] = 5
counter[3] = 2

for i in range(5):
    print(f'counter[{i}]={counter[i]}')
```

Which will give me the following output:

```
counter[0]=0
counter[1]=0
counter[2]=5
counter[3]=2
counter[4]=0
```

Basically it acts as if any element in the dictionary that has not been explicitly initialized has the value of zero, and will never throw an exception when accessing non-existing element.

Is there a similar entity in PHP, or is the only way to check each index when accessing in a loop?

I am looking for a way to avoid doing this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < numOfSomeResults; $i++) {
    if (isset($otherResult[$i]) {
        echo $otherResult[$i];
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
}
```

And do something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfSomeResults; $i++) {
    echo $counter[i];
}
```

Both the indexes and values I need to work with are integers if that helps.

Comment: There's no built-in equivalent, but you should surely write such a class…

Comment: This is what the null coalesce operator is for: `echo $counter[$i] ?? 0`

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks, this solves my problem! If it was an answer, I would have excepted it...

Comment: Do you actually need to show the non-existent elements such as 0 and 1 as 0 or just ignore them?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, it needs to be printed in an HTML table. The production code that I can't show here cross-referneces results from 3 separate SQL queries to print the table and two of the queries don't have results for all elements in the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reinventing the wheel and following on from [Alex's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483777/is-there-a-php-equvalent-to-pythons-counter-object#comment122813944_69483777), you can use the null coalescing operator (PHP 7+)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfSomeResults; $i++) {
    echo $counter[$i] ?? 0;
}
```

Some background information about what it does:
The null Coalescing operator is mainly used to **avoid the object function to return a NULL value rather returning a default optimized value**. It is used to avoid exception and compiler error as it does not produce E-Notice at the time of execution.

```
(Condition) ? (Statement1) ? (Statement2);
```

This same statement can be written as:

```
if ( isset(Condition) ) {
    return Statement1;
} else {
    return Statement2;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

Put '$' in front of 'i'. The code below must work.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < numOfSomeResults; $i++) {
    if (isset($otherResult[$i]) {
        echo $otherResult[$i];
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, but the lack of `$` was a typo, my question is specifically about avoiding the entire `if ... else` block.